# Можно ли подключить legacy mongo driver к PHP7

Tags: php, linux, yii2, mongodb

Ситуация следующая. На Dev сервере разрабатывается одновременно несколько проектов как на 5-й так и на 7-й версии PHP.

На Live сервере стоит

- PHP 5.5.23
- **mongo** 1.6.6

> extension_loaded("mongodb") = **false**
>
> extension_loaded("mongo") = **true**

На Dev сервере стоит

- PHP 7.0.8
- **mongodb** 1.1.8

> extension_loaded("mongodb") = **true**
>
> extension_loaded("mongo") = **false**

Cайт написан на Yii2, следовательно лезть и менять что-то в Framework дурная затея.

на Dev сервере начинает сыпать ошибки , вроде этих

> Class 'MongoDate' not found
>
> Class 'MongoClient' not found

Как понимаю это из-за обратной совместимости mongo и mongodb драйвера. Пробовал написать свои классы врапперы и обновить версии yiisoft/yii2 и yiisoft/yii2-mongodb. Но это тоже весьма плохой идеей показалось так как некоторые "экзотические" куски кода стали тоже несовместимы с новой версией.

Вот кусок composer.json с пакетами.

```
  "minimum-stability": "beta",
  "require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.4",
    "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "2.0.1",
  }

  "minimum-stability": "stable",
  "require": {
    "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "v1.1.4",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.9",
    "yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "2.1.0",
  }
```

Есть ли свет в конце тоннеля?

Comment: Правило dev/prod parity - при разработке и в продакшене должно быть максимально идентичное окружение. Если у вас нет возможности откатить прод до пятой версии, я бы рекомендовал разрабатывать проекты свежей версии PHP в вируталке.

Comment: Это слишком идеальные условия. Думал перенести разработку на локалку и мучать уже как угодно. Но тогда возникает необходимость поставить одновременно две версии PHP 5 и 7 паралельно. Как понимаю это достигается через cgi. Но сам таким никогда не занимался. Если есть мануал для чайников с последовательными шагами. Был бы признательным

Comment: Это не слишком идеальные условия, это необходимые условия вашей разработки. Есть phpbrew для разных версий

Comment: phpbrew подходит. Как раз копаю в этом нарпавлении. Поставил версию 5-ю версию в него. Теперь нужно сконфигурировать чтоб разделение было. Для php-cli помогло. Версия меняется после phpbrew use php-5.5.23. Как теперь такое же провернуть с Apache?

Comment: если честно, я плотно его не использовал, но, скорее всего, будет достаточно указать корректный путь в настройках (тот, в который скопилирует соответствующий файл модуля phpbrew)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы используете mongoDB для проэкта у вас есть только два варианта:

1. писать на php 5.* с использованием класса `MongoClient` откатить прод до этой версии php (на php7 пока нет расширения `mongo`)
2. либо переписать всё на расширение `mongodb` полностью и тогда будет вариант запуска и на php7.* и php5.* с расширением `mongodb`

Сталкнувшись с такой же проблемой я просто переписал проэкт на `mongodb` заменив `mongo` и его классы такие как `mongoClient` к сожалению в php7.* этого расширения нет (по крайней мере небыло на момент переписывания)

Answer (score 0):

Нет, старый MongoClient несовместим с PHP7 из-за внутренних различий в API с PHP5